# Proper synchronization use in java

Tags: java, synchronization, immutability

I have a list of **Firm** objects.

Each object has few properties which never change after initialization of the object.  One of the propeties is a list holding **User** objects which may grow or shrink over time.

i want for each **Firm** object to know how many **User** objects it has.

So my question is should i do it like this

```
List<Firm> firmsList = getFirmsList();

for(int i=0; i<firmsList.size(); i++)
{
    Firm firm = firmsList.get(i);
    synchronized(firm)
    {
         int usersCount = firm.getUsers().size();  
    } 
}
```

or should i synchronize the User object too? (Currently the list of **User** objects is accessed only within the **Firm** object )

Answer (score 1):

You say that `Firm` is immutable (its properties will never change after initialization of the object). If that's the case, then you do not need synchronization at all.

Comment: yes but the List inside the firm may grow or shrink :)

Comment: Than synchronize of list outside of the loop

Comment: @JoroSeksa But you said that its properties will never change after initialization. So, that's not true then - if that's happening then your class `Firm` is **not** immutable.

Comment: @Jesper i meant there are not set methods. Sorry for not being very clear. I fixed the question.

Comment: About whether you should synchronize on `User` objects: Nobody can tell based on the information you've given. Is `User` immutable? What are you doing with the `User` objects?

Answer (score 0):

Add a convenience method like `Firm#getUserSize()` or return a unmodifiable list `java.util.Collections.unmodifiableList(List<? extends T>)` to become a **immutable** `Firm`.

Depending on working code around `Firm#getUsers()` may return a synchronized `Collection` instead.